# Python open() as write giving wrong encoding in json

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding

I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'id': 5677240, 'name': 'Conjunto de Panelas antiaderentes com 05 Peças Paris', 'quantity': 21, 'price': '192.84', 'category': 'Panelas'}
```

But when I try to write it to a JSON file, there's a little mess on the encoding:

```
{"id": 5677240, "name": "Conjunto de Panelas antiaderentes com 05 Pe\u00e7as Paris", "quantity": 21, "price": 192.84, "category": "Panelas"}
```

I've already tried putting encoding='utf-8 and using locale as false, but neither helped me.

Comment: Important to note, I have read it like this:
 bd = json.load(open('brokendatabase.json','r', encoding='utf-8'))

Answer (score 0):

You will have to disable `ensure_ascii` while writing to a file.

```
import json

data = {'id': 5677240, 'name': 'Conjunto de Panelas antiaderentes com 05 Peças Paris', 'quantity': 21, 'price': '192.84', 'category': 'Panelas'}

with open("a.json", "w") as f:
     json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Output in file:

```
{"id": 5677240, "name": "Conjunto de Panelas antiaderentes com 05 Peças Paris", "quantity": 21, "price": "192.84", "category": "Panelas"}
```

Comment: Instead of \u00e7 I got this: �

Comment: I added a comment, I used enconding utf8, maybe that's the issue